# Picking correct date from array of dates - Algo

Tags: algorithm, excel, vba

I am stuck with this stupid logic. Please help me. My problem is explained as below:

I have an array of elements with specific dates with factor changes on the effective dates for the month(s) duration

> ### Element   EffectiveDate(mm/dd/yyyy)  Factor
>
> XYZ1                03/02/2014                                              0.8
>   
> XYZ2                04/02/2014                                              0.7
>   
> XYZ3                05/04/2014                                              0.9

Now I have to generate report for each day, with the date range given as input from the user.
So the question is how can i pick the date and element from my array with respect to the current date(from the date range provided). Something like this --

Date Range (03/31/2014 to 05/30/2014)

> ### Date         Element   Factor
>
> 03/31/2014        XYZ1              0.8
>   
> 04/01/2014        XYZ1              0.8
>   
> 04/02/2014        XYZ2              0.7
>   
> 04/03/2014        XYZ2              0.7
>   
>             |
>   
>             |
>   
>             |
>   
> 05/03/2014        XYZ2              0.7
>   
> 05/04/2014        XYZ3              0.9
>   
> 05/05/2014        XYZ3              0.9

I am working on excel vba, any help would be highly appreciated.
I am basically stuck in picking up the correct element based on the current date (from date range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comeup with the table with range of data. Calculate another field like effectiveTo. The array would look like this:

```
Element   EffectiveDate(mm/dd/yyyy)    EffectiveTill(mm/dd/yyyy)      Factor
XYZ1                03/02/2014          04/01/2014                       0.8 
XYZ1                04/01/2014          12/31/2099(maxdate)              0.8 
XYZ2                04/02/2014          04/03/2014                       0.7 
XYZ2                04/03/2014          05/03/2014                       0.7 
XYZ2                05/03/2014          12/31/2099(maxdate)              0.7 
XYZ3                05/04/2014          05/05/2014                       0.9
```

Sorted by EffectiveDate and Element.
Once you have it and just traverse the array with the date range which fall between Effectivedate and EffectiveTill and write your desire output.